# How to put cursor on every other line (on alternate lines)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I put cursor on every other line (on alternate lines).

For example, I want to put cursor on line 1,3,5,7....

How can I do that?

I know I can do that by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd>. But there are too many lines and an  easier way will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number) and use the command **Place cursor based on line number, uses boolean expression** (`selectby.lineNr`)

In the expression box of the command type

```
(n-1)%2==0
```

If you want to limit the number of cursors add an extra criterion

```
(n-1)%2==0 && n<100
```

If you place the cursor on line 1 you can use

```
c+2k
```

Read the extension page for other possibilities

You can set key binding for often use expressions.

**Edit**

Feature suggestion by @blueray

In v1.8.0 I have added `inselection`.

If you want to limit the cursors to the current selection(s) you can use the expression

```
c+2k && inselection
```

Comment: I am already using "select by" extension. But i did not know it could do that. Thanks.

Comment: @blueray Maybe have a new look at the extension page, I have added a few new things in the last months, you can now remove the first or last multi cursor

Comment: Is there any way I can use the keybinding on selected text only?

Comment: @blueray I will add this feature, for now use the `&& n<150`, I will change it to `&& inselection`

Comment: @blueray have a look at v1.8.0

Comment: wonderful! I am using `"lineNrEx": "c+2k && inselection"`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a regex:

1. Find: `^(.*\n){1}.*$`
2. With focus on the find input, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  It will select all those matches - every two lines.  Or if focus is in the editor, hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - it'll do the same thing.
3. <kbd>Home</kbd> to put cursor at beginning of those selections. (If you have spaces or tabs at the beginning of a line, just hit <kbd>Home</kbd> until you are at the beginning.)
4. <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> or <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to move those cursors where you want.

[image: put a cursor on every other line demo]

---

Obviously this scales pretty easily:

Find: `^(.*\n){2}.*$` for every third line, `^(.*\n){3}.*$` for every fourth line, etc.

Comment: The regex only works with words (`\w`). Can you please give an example of how this works with lines.

Comment: I updated and simplified the regex. I replaced the gif.